# Add properties to context in cordova plugin for Application Insights

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, azure-application-insights

I use cordova plugin with Application Insight named cordova-plugin-ms-appinsights (https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-ms-appinsights/blob/master/README.md) and I tried to add my properties to context, that through each request application will send additional info, for example code name of my application.

I tried as below:

appInsights.context.application.codename = "code name app";
appInsights.trackEvent("my event");

and this did not work. 
Can I add additional info to context?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues:

1) Cordova plugin seems to use an old version of the JS SDK. You can try to update it manually after it pulls down the old one (take the most recent one from https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/dist/ai.0.js)

2) The feature that adds data to *ALL* telemetry items is not released yet. It was implemented recently - [see JS SDK commit on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/commit/9c8102bbb89551078c709a79e46ec85e836d048a). You can either wait a bit until it's released or get the latest from master and compile it yourself (and take the result from /JavaScript/min/ai.min.js)

A hacky alternative may be to create a wrapper on top of SDK methods like trackEvent() which adds the data you need (I'm sorry for giving you the JS SDK code equivalent as I haven't used cordova plugin myself):

```
// this is you implementation of custom data to be attached
// to all telemetry items.
// It needs to return JSON - as it's expected format for custom properties.
// In this specific case you'll create a custom property 'hey' with value 'yo'
var getMyDataJson = function() {
  return { hey: "yo"};
}    

// this is your wrapper, you'll call it instead of appInsights.trackEvent()
var myTrackEvent = function(data) {
  var toBeAttachedToAllItems = getMyDataJson();
  appInsights.trackEvent(data, toBeAttachedToAllItems);
}
<...>
// somewhere later you track your telemetry
// this will call your getMyDataJson() function which'll attach
// custom data to your event.
myTrackEvent("tracked!")
```